# How to access state within a property of a React class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React Class Component of which I would like to separate a part of the rendered JSX but I don't seem to be able to get the Component's state within the separated JSX (as a property of the class).

The actual situation is very similar to this example

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      x: 1
    };
  }

  button = (
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        x = {this.state.x}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button> // this works!
        {this.button} // this doesn't :(
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to read `this.state.x` directly in the render() method, it works as expected, but when I put the code in the `button` property and inject it in the render() method by calling `this.button` inside brackets then `this.state` is undefined and I'm unable to read the state.

I tried using an utility method like `getX = () => this.state.x` and called it inside the `button` property but it doesn't get the state.

I also tried setting another property `_this = this` and calling `this._this.getX` inside the brackets. This didn't work either.

Any idea on how to get it to work? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow function you will get the implicit reference of the component instance:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      x: 1
    };
  }

  renderButton = () => (
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        x = {this.state.x}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button>
        {this.renderButton()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Using function syntax, you need to bind `this` in constructor:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      x: 1
    };
    renderButton = renderButton.bind(this);
  }

  renderButton() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button>
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        x = {this.state.x}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ x: 2 })}>{this.state.x}</button>
        {this.renderButton()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At the end i've surrendered on using a method for rendering the separated JSX (I didn't want too because I'm in a very complex Component and there is unexpected behaviour when changing stuff), but the question stands open: isn't there any way to achieve the same result by using a class property instead of a class method?

Comment: no there is not. see, a component is a function that return a React element, not a property. `<Component />` is jsx sugar syntax to invoke that function, so it needs to be a method. fwiw, you don't need to bind your methods if you declare them as arrow function. you also dont need to invoke constructor function, you can just type `state = { x: 1 }`